# Registering new device tokens to topics to replace previous device token

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app users are subscribed to a variety of cloud messaging topics.  Occasionally a users device token/ID  will change.  I need to lookup the old token, grab all the topics the user was subscribed to - subscribe the users new token to all the same topics and then remove the old device tokens from those groups.

However, I am noticing that as soon as the user gets a new device token it seems they are instantly removed from the previous topics.  Thus I am not able to retrieve all the subscribed topics with the old token/ID - and if I can't do that, it seems I have no way to subscribe the users new token to all the appropriate topics because I am unable to find out what the topics were.

Is there some trick or method that I need to do to deal with this issue?

Comment: Consider using a database to store their subscriptions, which you should always be able to query.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks - I am already doing that but was using the FCM to grab subscribed topics.  I will switch my code to rely on my DB...topic/deviceID management is via FCM or APi is pretty weak.  I guess a better way of say things is my original method worked in some cases...and others it did not due to the above reason.  Is there some known amount of time old/changed device tokens are deleted from Google's FCM db's?  How long will dead device tokens hang around?...I can't find any documentation regarding this.

Comment: If you questions about the undocumented implementation details of Firebase products, please contact Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support